# QProcess fails to execute a simple console program

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I compiled a c++ source file from the Qt app I am creating. Now I want to run the exe file generated and also to redirect its input and output to txt files. But when I try to run it from QProcess, it fails to *execute* with exit code -2.

This is how I compiled the file using QProcess -

```
arguments << fileName << "-o" << exeFileName << "-static";
connect(compileProcess, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(compiled()));
compileProcess->start(QString("g++"), arguments);
```

And this is how I run the exe from QProcess in the slot compiled() -

```
runProcess->setStandardInputFile(inputFilename);
runProcess->setStandardOutputFile(QFileInfo(exeFileName).path() + "/output.txt");
int code = runProcess->execute(exeFileName); //code = -2
```

The program runs fine when I start it manually. So, why can't it be started from QProcess?
I am working with Qt 5.0.2 on Windows 7

This is the source file I am compiling -

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s;s
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you add a `readAllStandardError` and print the contents, does it have any information? The `-2` is usually it fails to either open the executable with the correct permissions, or it can't find the executable so also double check that the `exeFileName` is pointing to the correct place.

Comment: `readAllStandardError` doesn't return any information. And I verified that `exeFileName` points to the correct file.

Comment: the only other thing I can think of is the QProcess is setting to the application working directory rather than looking at the `exeFileName` path.

Comment: There's a working directory method: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html#setWorkingDirectory basically QProcess sets it to the directory your application is running from, but occasionally it can cause problems.

Comment: Okay, but `exeFileName` has the absolute path to the file, even then QProcess can't find the file?

Comment: If it has the absolute path it *should* be fine. You might need to do `QDir::toNativeSeparators(exeFileName)` to convert to Windows formatting thinking about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. The exe file path had spaces in it and Qt did not implicitly add quotes around it. Adding quotes explicitly did the job.

```
runProcess->start("\"" + exeFileName + "\"");
```